# Did Apache Flink drop the StreamOperatorTestHarness classes, or did they move to a different artifact?

Tags: maven, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using intellij, maven 3, and flink 1.15.1 to write a stateful streaming job. I am trying to write unit tests for my custom KeyedProcessFunction and tried following the documentation [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/testing/) along with adding the dependency mentioned [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/configuration/testing/). I'm interested in using the KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness class, but I can't find that class in any of my dependencies (redacted pom posted below). The only time I can find the class is by including

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

which is from the previous version. Flink >= 1.15.0 doesn't require the scala dependent libraries now, so there is no flink-streaming-java_2.12 for 1.15.1.

Did the class I want to use get moved somewhere else or purposefully excluded? I've tried all the google foo I know, and I can find the class in the flink repo, but not in any of the flink dependencies I've tried so far, outside of that <=1.14.5 one. Am I doing something wrong or missing some documentation? Is using the 1.14.5 library my only option or is there some new type of test utils that I don't know about?

Pom dependencies that don't have the class:

```
...
        <flink.version>1.15.1</flink.version>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that I've figured it out, but my maven knowledge is limited so I'm not sure what the pros and cons are. Also I imagine future versions of flink will change this. The bonus is that I can use the latest flink version without including in older code.

I added these dependencies for testing (for 1.15.1 at least):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

I came across the flink readme about [artifacts](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.15/docs/README.md#flink-artifact) and the classifier tag, and I knew that the classes I needed were in flink-streaming-java package, specifically in its tests section. So including dependency for flink-streaming-java with the `<classifier>tests</classifier>` tag made the test classes available.

For what it's worth, there is a cryptic warning in the doc:

> Useful when users should be pulling in Flink tests dependencies. This is mostly for the test harnesses and probably not what you want.

I still needed the flink-test-utils for the mock runner it provides.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Is this a deficiency with Flink documentation here https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/configuration/testing/?

Comment: I certainly think so. It might be missing because they don't want to encourage dependencies on those classes, but that's purely speculative. It might just need a pr to update the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In the link mentioned above,

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/testing/

It says,

"Be aware that AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness and its derived classes are currently not part of the public API and can be subject to change."

I have run into this issue before and have not come across any artifacts that actually contain those classes.

Update:

TL;DR
Build from source and include the jar directly.

Solution:
Locate the flink source code from the github page for the correct version:
https://github.com/apache/flink/releases/tag/release-x.xx

```
cd /path/to/flink-release-x.xx
unzip flink-release-x.xx.zip
```

unzip the file, and follow the instructions to build the project. This usually means running something like,

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Ensure you are using the correct version for both maven and java. The maven version can usually be seen by looking in the pom.xml file for one of these two properties: maven.compiler.source or maven.compiler.target

If you are using the latest version, you can simply clone the entire project and use the maven build script. However, this didn't work for my case as I needed an earlier version.

Once built, the test harnesses are located in this jar:
flink-release-x.xx/flink-streaming-java/target/flink-streaming-java-x.xx-tests.jar

You can include this jar directly by adding it to your classpath using the IDE, gradle, maven, etc. In my case I copied the jar directly to this folder:
/libs/
and included it by adding the following to my build.gradle file:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

You may also need to add the following runtime jar:
flink-release-x.xx/flink-runtime/target/flink-runtime-x.xx.jar

For Intellij, you can add the jars directly by going to,
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> "+" -> JARs or Directories

Hope this helps!